# Google play services location request

Tags: android, android-location

I have a service to track location. The services works fine and logs the location periodically.
When the user turns off the Location in the device then it stops logging location which is fine.
But when the user turns on the location again, the service does not resumes tracking the location though it is running. Did anyone else experience this problem?
I am using Google play services location and using the standard codes from the documentation

Comment: We need to see some code or there is no way to tell, but likely you aren't restarting your location listener/service when you restart your location provider.

Comment: when the user turns on the location again .. Start the service again.

Comment: When the service is already running, how do I know that the user turned off the location in the device? I don't think there is a way to determine that in android or is there? On what basis should I restart the service?